# flutter: check app internet connection when it runs

Tags: flutter

i'm building flutter app and i want to check internet connection when user enters the app so if there is no connection it should show a page declares that " no internet connection please try again.."
i used code below but it doesn't work , when i'm in debug mode i turned off wifi and app still running, is there a way to do it?
thanks in advance

```html
main() async {
  // if your flutter > 1.7.8 :  ensure flutter activated
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await translator.init(
    localeDefault: LocalizationDefaultType.device,
    languagesList: <String>['en', 'ar'],
    assetsDirectory: 'assets/langs/',
    apiKeyGoogle: '<Key>', // NOT YET TESTED
  );

  runApp(
    LocalizedApp(
      child: Notification(),
    ),
  );
}

class Notification extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NotificationState createState() => _NotificationState();
}

class _NotificationState extends State<Notification> {
  var subscription;
  var connectionStatus;

  @override
  void initState() {
    subscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {         
      setState(() => connectionStatus = result );
    });
    checkInternetConnectivity();
    // checkLoginStatus();
    super.initState();
  }

  checkInternetConnectivity() {
    if (connectionStatus == ConnectivityResult.none) {
      return Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "Check your internet connection",
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          gravity: ToastGravity.TOP,
          timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 16.0
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    subscription.cancel();
  }
  
    
  

  //  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    return MultiProvider(
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete, there is something missing at the end, can you complete it?

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the `connectionStatus` every time when connectivity changes, which is fine. But you also need to check if that `connectionStatus` is valid. In other words, after every connectivity change call the `checkInternetConnectivity();` method.

```
subscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {         
        setState(() => connectionStatus = result);
        checkInternetConnectivity();
});
```

If you are using `connectionStatus` only to show the toast message then there is no need to rebuild the widgets tree for that (which you are doing by calling `setState` method).

Also, you can use StreamBuilder in your widgets tree and build the corresponding widget based on the connectivity status.

Sample code:

```
//Put this line outside of the build method
final connectivity = Connectivity();

//Use this in the build method
StreamBuilder<ConnectivityResult>(
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<ConnectivityResult> snapshot) {
    if(!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data != ConnectivityResult.none) { //Connectivity hasn't change or there is no problems with connection
      return Container( //Return widget when there is connection
        color: Colors.green,
      );
    }

    return Container(
      color: Colors.green,
    );
  },
  stream: Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged,
)
```

*Please note that this code is not tested and it's a proof of concept.*

Comment: thats worked good, but is there a way to show page instead of toast?

Comment: Actually i tried to return a page instead of return Fluttertoast.showToast but it didn't work

Comment: I tested ur code it shows only toaster warning "check internet connection" still not showing the green page.However, i added the streamBuilder inside the  Widget build(BuildContext context)